# How to maintain the appropriate file type (MIME) when moving a documents (pdf, xls) from one library to another

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a workflow that I created in moving a document from one library to another library and it works fine for word documents, but when moving excel or PDF files, the file is moved, but the filetype seems to be a word file type.

I am using Create Item in creating the item in the new library.  There does not seem to be a way to update the file type or mime type using this command.